# OpenGL - change hue of texture without shaders

Tags: opengl

I am drawing 2D Sprites with legacy OpenGL (2.0 or less) commands and I want to be able to change rendering behavior without using Fragment-Shaders, especially I want to be able to change the hue of sprites to arbitrary colors, respecting Alpha-Values of the sprite as to make only visible parts colored differently. Is there an easy way to do that?

EDIT: To make an example: In the RPG-Maker series you can tint any entity on the map scenes or battler-sprites in the battle scenes, like when something gets struck, the sprites for the attack-animation get drawn while at the same time, the sprite of the hit target flashes red - the duration,color and intensity of everything can be adjusted - right now I am just looking for the bare struckture about how to change the hue of any sprite, the rest is only modeling and building up from that.

Code: This is what I do to draw a sprite transparent, it seems to work just as advertised.

`[...] init(){
        glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
}[...]`

drawSpriteTransparent(Sprite sprite, int x, int y, float transparency) {
        Texture t = sprite.getTexture();
        double tx = sprite.getTexutreX();
        double ty = sprite.getTextureY();
        double tw = sprite.getWidthInTexture();
        double th = sprite.getHeightInTexture();
        glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, t.getTextureID());
        glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1f - transparency);
        glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        {
            glTexCoord2d(tx, ty);
            glVertex3d(x, y, 0);
            glTexCoord2d(tx, ty + th);
            glVertex3d(x, y + sprite.getHeight(), 0);
            glTexCoord2d(tx + tw, ty + th);
            glVertex3d(x + sprite.getWidth(), y + sprite.getHeight(), 0);
            glTexCoord2d(tx + tw, ty);
            glVertex3d(x + sprite.getWidth(), y, 0);
        }
        glEnd();
        glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

EDIT: using `glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE )` does not yield the desired results, though using `glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD )` at least enables me to increase the color intensity of a desired color, though it does not allow me to increase a value to a point where each visible pixel is completely of the desired color (What I would like would be something like:  `(1,0,0,0.1)`  -> a bit more red  `(1,0,0,0.5)`  -> a lot more red  `(1,0,0,1)`  -> every rendered pixel is 100% red, though pixels with original alpha value 0 are still not rendered)

Comment: You could light them differently or change the current color but I'm sensing that's not what you want to do. I don't think you can use palettes either since you want to keep alpha values. You could generate a texture based on the current texture by replacing certain color values if you have a known number of possibilities. Can you be more specific or send a snapshot of what you want to do?

Comment: It's not clear what you want, but if you just want to tint a texture, use `glTexEnvi( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE )`, and the current color will affect the texture.

Comment: Can you please explain how you would use that to get the desired result? I am looking at tutorials but they mostly talk about mixing textures, where I want to mix a texture with a color (though these two goals might not be that far apart)

Comment: If you use the glTexEnvi setting that @JWWalker suggested then you would just change glColor4f to use whichever color you want to blend with and the result will be the texture color multiplied by the color from glColor4f.

Comment: That means I can basically only filter out color, not add (as the values only range from 0 to 1)

Comment: even with older OpenGL you should be able to avoid immediate mode? or I'm missing something? and, by the way, why are you limited to OpenGL < 2.0?

Comment: @SargeBorsch mainly because of challenge reasons

Comment: @salbeira this looks like a pointless challenge... you will gain more if you learn some modern OpenGL stuff instead. It's far more interesting too.

Comment: Right now I am actually learning some glsl and all the horrible and annoying stuff that comes with it (create shader file, load shader file, compile shader file, link shaders into program, create vao, create vbos, bind vbos into vao, don't forget to save the IDs of all that stuff somewhere ... don't forget to unbind everything afterwards ... then to render bind everything again ... push stuff down the modified pipeline in a way noone can read the code and sees what should happen on a whim ... (and the last part is what buggs me the most and what I like about the fixed pipeline)

Comment: You can use shaders with immediate mode OpenGL. That would greatly simplify your problem since you would just need to do a texture lookup in the fragment shader and then use the mix function to blend it with your base color. I agree with @SargeBorsch that you will benefit more from learning modern OpenGL though.

Comment: @salbeira Nobody forces you to write unreadable code even if it deals with VAO, VBO, shaders and other "scary" things from OpenGL world. You can always organize your code so it will look good. Especially in Java (I guess, your code snippets are in Java, right?)

Comment: The thing is that I would still love to know if it can be done with the fixed pipeline - just so that I know it.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could do something like this using fixed pipe multitexturing (loading your tint as a separate texture), as it has a dizzying array of options as to how the two textures are blended together.

Comment: Well an idea that works with Java2D was that I rendered a tint mask onto another Buffered Image that respected the alpha values and then rendered the tint above the original, though that contained a lot of work that I think OpenGL can do easier. Also I do not really want to consider using render to texture stuff as I want to keep my code as simple as possible ...

Comment: this can't change hue arbitrarily, only apply a "color filter". but with legacy mode there are hardly any other options